# PHP can Strlen be trusted for mission critical banking applications?

Tags: php

i am wondering when i check the length of the string with strlen function in php

it says its 32. however when i open that in a notepad or notepad++ i can see some empty spaces in the file (incorrect alignment with the other lines,

**since i am doing a banking application strlen is critical to be 100% correct.**

i am just wondering should i keep trusting this output or should i moved to something else like

```
mb_strlen
```

what is the best function to be trusted in normal ASCII character set ?

Comment: Why not just trim the string and then perform strlen operation! when dealing with critical string operation i prefer first you run a string sterilization before doing anything.

Comment: I think you must be dealing with mixed strings, that's why ASCII Character comes into the role.

Comment: Perhaps less obtusely, what do you want to count? The number of bytes in the string for storage in database, or the number of characters in the string for validation, or the length of the string when displayed on a certain font, or something else. Whether or not strlen is correct depends on what you're trying to do with the string, all I can say is that strlen is correct for its intended purpose; whether what you have in mind matches that purpose is another story.

Comment: i did the trim function before actually i want to count the number of characters in the string for validation

Comment: @mahen3d I know it's passed some time, but I think they wanted to know if you need to count human characters required for that text (multi-bytes count - done via mb_strlen()) or storage space required for that text (bytes - done via strlen()). Sorry if this can be confusing but I can't really describe our doubts better than this without more background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `strlen()` or `mb_strlen()` depends on your servers setup, if it uses the `mb_string extension` or not. Though usually `strlen()` is overloaded with `mb_strlen()` anyway in those cases. Apart from that the computed values are 100% correct.

The difference you might see is how text (especially multibyte  strings) is visualized if you open it in a text displaying application. It is much more likely that you get a misleading information there.

Comment: I think we should not say that it depends from the server setup, but from the purpose of the user (and of course it depends from the availability of that function in the current setup but it does not mean that - if missing - the user should use strlen - since we know they do different things). Just to avoid tips that could be misleading for unexperienced users.

Comment: The OP himself suggests `mb_strinlen()` so we can safely assume he is aware of the function and will realize it is not available when used.